# iPhone Finding AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, appdelegate

I am trying to create MAC application.
My input is --> Source Code Folder of an existing iPhone Application.

Using my application I want to insert an extra screen in the existing application. The extra screen will be always the first screen.

Since I want to Automate this, I have written a MAC application which browses through the Source code folder and replaces the first screen of app with my extra screen. This is working perfectly for Single View Application where I get the AppDelegate class name from the main.m file ( by parsing UIApplicationMain(argc,argv,MyAppDelegate,nil) ) line.

The application fails when the third argument is 'nil' in some of the applications (which may depend on the implementer or type of project).

Is it possible to make my application generic for all kind of applications?

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would only have to search (recursively) the folder for all `.h` files, and then detect the name of the class that implements `UIApplicationDelegate`. There should not *usually* have more than one, and would work with the defaults templates I guess.